# Search not searching each column in custom list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, custom-list, sharepoint-server

Good Morning.

I have created a Custom List which is acting as a corporate directory. Using the search box in the "Standard View".

It will only search certain columns. i.e. First Name and Employee Number. It won't bring up any results if I search by Last Name.

Any help?

I am using SharePoint 2013 On Premise.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have data in last name field? Search takes some time to crawl the data and show in search results. When you have added data in last name column?

Comment: How are you searching for last name?  "Smith" or "LastName=Smith"? Only the first will work unless you have setup Site Columns and Search Managed Columns.

Comment: Why not use the built in people search page. It searches against the crawled User Profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot the issue as following:

1. Go to Central Administration->search service application->Search schema->Crawled property, check if the relevant column name listed in it.
2. Go to site settings->searchable columns, check if the column is excluded from the site index.
3. Go to list settings->Advanced settings->click “Reindex list” button, then start a full/incremental crawl in search service application and check again.